# How to get customers' subscriptions (Active and Cancelled) using Laravel cashier?

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, strip, laravel-cashier

basically, I am using Laravel Cashier and I have a single user with multiple subscriptions. I want to get the user active and canceled both subscriptions.

```
$request->user()->asStripeCustomer()->subscriptions;
```

this can return only active subscriptions but I need all types of subscriptions

Comment: The title is not grammatically correct. There's a verb missing after "How to". Please edit.

Comment: "I want to get the user active and canceled both subscriptions" - this looks like you need to get the _active user_. Instead, I think, you need to get active and canceled subscriptions, right? Could you make it clear in your post?

Comment: @ahmad waqas did you manage to get this right? I'm also trying to figure out how to get all users who have active subscriptions...